# MySQL query AND PHP challenge..Splitting Semicolon values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using PHP/code igniter to display data.
In my table (Products),I have a field called "ProductCategory".Since a product can belong to more than one category and according to my project requirement and XML file,this field was populated like this:

**id**                  121

**ProductCode**        m34

**Name**               Nokia 6800

**ProductCategory**     Mobiles;Casings

**ProductMainCategory**     Handsets

**sort_order**           3

////////////////////// SECOND Product//////////////////////////

**id**                 344

**ProductCode**        32344

**Name**               Xbox 360 Black

**ProductCategory**     Consoles

**ProductMainCategory**    Special Offers

**sort_order**           5

////////////////////// Third Product//////////////////////////

**id**                  3433

**ProductCode**        342zxc4

**Name**               Iphone 5

**ProductCategory**     Accessories;Mobiles 4G

**ProductMainCategory**     Handsets

**sort_order**           3

and so on .....

**QUESTION:**

Since ,i have separated the products with two categories with semcolon (;) so 
splitted the semicolon product category';' values into two categories and passed them in url to display products according to the "ProductCategory" and "ProductMainCategory".
I am using query string /uri segment to display my products.

```
<?
$id2=urldecode($this->uri->segment(3)); //  gets values like Handsets
$id=urldecode($this->uri->segment(4));  // gets values like Mobiles
$this->db->like('ProductCategory',$id);

$this->db->or_like('ProductCategory',';'.$id);
//$this->db->not_like('ProductCategory','Store 8');
//$this->db->like('ProductCategory',';'.$id);
$this->db->where('ProductMainCategory',$id2);
$this->db->order_by('sort_order','asc');
$query_data=$this->db->get('Products');
?>
```

Based on the Code and MYSQL data,How can i display my single product so that it could appear under each category separately(according to the query string/uri segment value) like this:

```
Handsets¬
         |-Mobiles
                  |--- Nokia 6800
         |-Casings
                  |---- Nokia 6800    

         |-Mobiles 4G
                  |--- Iphone 5 
         |-Accessories
                  |---- Iphone 5    


  Special Offers¬
                |-Consoles
                         |---Xbox 360 Black
```

I have shown the required query output in tree structure for clarification.You can compare it with the data above for clarifcation.Kindly help me.Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Comment: I know about normalisation.i want duplicate values from single table as it is the requirement of the project

Comment: It's a requirement of the project that the database should be badly designed?

Comment: @MarkBaker.I have been using normalisation techniques for the last 6 years of development.In this case,I am dumping data directly from the SAGE XML and XML doesn't know about normalisation.Does it ?? :)

Comment: @Bilal Khalid c'mon, just get rid of `ProductCategory` and implement it with `product_to_category` relation. You can then achieve what you need to with a simple JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you have a table of valid product categories, called ProductCategories.  You can fetch the products by category using a complicated join condition.  Here is an example that counts the number of products in each category:

```
select pc.ProductCategory, count(*) as NumProducts
from Products p join
     ProductCategories pc
     on concat(';', p.ProductCategory, ';') like concat('%;', pc.ProductCategory, '%;')
group by pc.ProductCategory
```

If you don't have a ProductCategories table, you can make one in the query:

```
select pc.ProductCategory, count(*) as NumProducts
from Products p join
     (select 'Console' as ProductCategory union all
      select . . .
     ) pc
     on concat(';', p.ProductCategory, ';') like concat('%;', pc.ProductCategory, '%;')
group by pc.ProductCategory
```

However, I would only advise doing this for an ad hoc one-off query, since new categories may be added over time.